# i am trying to get id from table name data base to stor in variable so i can use in another table it give sql syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

here is the code there is catch close but i delete it so can anyone replay to me

String id = null;
            String root="root",student="root";

```
        String name=jTextField1.getText();
      try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();


        Connection      
      con=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection
      ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306

      /dijlafinal1",root,student);
        String query2="SELECT * FROM name WHERE name like ? ";    
        PreparedStatement pstm2=null;
        pstm2=con.prepareStatement(query2);


       pstm2.setString(1,"%"+name+"%");
       ResultSet rs =    pstm2.executeQuery(query2 ); 
        while (rs.first()){

         String name1=rs.getString("name");
          id=     rs.getString("id");
          int epo =rs.getInt("epo");
         }              
        jTextField2.setText(id);
```

}

Comment: Can you share the error description/exception's stack trace?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the no-argument version of [`executeQuery()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()), i.e.

```
ResultSet rs = pstm2.executeQuery();
```

The reason is that you've already prepared the statement when you called `con.prepareStatement(query2)`. Calling `executeQuery(query2)` will throw away the prepared SQL and execute the query without bind variables, leaving the `?` in place -- as the error message suggests.

Comment: can you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821105/am-trying-to-search-for-value-from-tabel-using-jtext-filed-and-it-give-error-jav?noredirect=1#comment59309472_35821105

Comment: Move `pstm2.setString(1,fname);` one line down, _after_ you've assigned a value to `pstm2`.

Comment: wow i got headache and that what i should've done awwwch  !!!
thx man you are the best

Answer (score 0):

When working with a PreparedStatement you always call the `.execute...` methods *without* any arguments because you have already supplied the SQL command text with the `.prepareStatement` call. So

```java
ResultSet rs =    pstm2.executeQuery(query2 );
```

is incorrect. You need to simply do

```java
ResultSet rs =    pstm2.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if it might work if you use this?

```
pstm2.setString(1,"'%"+name+"%'");
```

Comment: have you debugged this?  Are you sure you're getting a value for the name?  From everything I've read your syntax is correct in the PreparedStatement.

Comment: Sorry, wrong answer. When working with a parametrized query we never include string delimiters, either in the command text or the parameter values.

Comment: i tried to   String  s= " \"%dmnak%\" ";                                                                                                           String query2="SELECT * FROM name WHERE name like "+s;